# ASP.NET Menu Control getting padded with white space on IE8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, aspmenu-control

If you have used the ASP.Net menu control on your website and recently updated your browser to IE8, you will probably have noticed your menu no longer renders properly.  You may also have noticed this in Firefox as well.  The menu will probably look just fine in IE6 & IE7.

So why is the ASP.Net menu being padded with space and why don't the drop downs render in IE8?

Answer (score 1):

First of all let me explain **I am not claiming this as my solution** but I thought I would post the question and solution here because it took me a while to find it.

After a bit of searching it turns out there are two problems.  One is a problem with .Net2.0 on your server and the second to do with the menu control adding some rubbish into your menu.

(1) Down load and update your server with MS hotfix KB969612

[HotFix Link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=18157)

(2) Read up on how Sakyad found the solution of adding this property to your menu control

SkipLinkText=""

[Sakyad solution](http://blogs.iis.net/sakyad/archive/2009/04/11/asp-net-menu-control-getting-padded-with-white-space-on-ie8.aspx)

(3) Happy Rendering!